# What chemistry software are there for Ubuntu?

Tags: software-recommendation, package-management

I am looking into Organic Chemistry and would like to know, if there are any packages that can help me to visualize better.

Topics that I am interested in:

- Covalend Bonds
- Hybridization
- Resonance Structure
- Isomers

Comment: Have a look here: https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/department/chemistry/

Comment: I found a nice periodic table in software center (just search periodic) I know its not exactly what you are looking for but could be useful maby ?

Comment: Kalzium is an excellent periodic table with many extras (3d visualiation of atoms, numerous graphs, etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Rasmol](http://www.rasmol.org/) is available for *nix. It is probably the most popular molecular visualization tool around.

[image: Install via the software center]

Answer (score 0):

You could always try browsing the software center. There's a Science and Engineering section and even a Chemistry sub-section.

Comment: but i can't find what i need

Comment: That's why i asked that here. If anyone can point me to a package that satisfies these

Answer (score 0):

there are a lot  of chemistry package's  at

http://www.redbrick.dcu.ie/~noel/linux4chemistry/linux4chemistry.py

marvin is one of them, I actually use it to predict nmr